# Javascript should I declare mutable objects with const

Tags: javascript, constants, mutation

I have question about consts/lets in JS and mutable objects.

Basically, should I use const to declare objects eg. Arrays that are able to mutate with .push? Is not that the `consts` should stay as they were declared, without any mutation and if there is one, it should be declared with `let`?

The vast majority projects uses Eslint rules to force `const` over `let` when value is not reassinged. Is there any benefit of using `const`?

What I found is this [article](https://catalin.red/es6-const-is-not-constant-immutable/) but it still not solving my problem *Should I declare mutable objects with const*

Comment: Absolutely, if the variable name doesn't get reassigned. Mutation is completely different.

Comment: That clear for me, but in C++ or event PHP class const can not be mutated when declared with const. It's a bit confusing when some languages allows to mutate variables and some not. Shouldn't we keep in mind to declare objects that mutates with let to follown good practices ?

Comment: Use `const`. `const` does not care for the inner keys (unless they are frozen). `const` is there to assure no later assigmnent `=` is performed over that *in-variable* or the same name is used. So if you have `const ob = {a:0}` you cannot later do `ob =`. That does not means you cannot modify the contents of your unfrozen Array or Object. But you can always use (if you don't want to go one-by-one Object property) the handy `Object.assign(ob, {a:1,b:2});` which will give you `{a:1, b:2}` even if `ob` was defined as const. Or go the old way: `ob.a=1; ob.b=2`

Comment: Use `const` in JavaScript as it means for JavaScript, not for PHP or some other language.

Comment: You are right, but it's not reffering to problem. Keyword `const` brings ffirst thought that not only instance/memory  reffernce, but also value of assigned object can not be changed. Those differences are little bit wierd between languages. But even if some language allows us to do such a things should we do that or just do it "the right way"?

PS. I know that `const object = Object.freeze({ a: 1 })` is kind a C++ `const`